# Social login (google) with a flutter app using piano io backend. Is there a way to do log a user in and get an access token for piano

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0

I'm attempting to log users in that use piano.io as a backend. This is a new flutter app  and while I can use the api to do password logins. I need to support google/apple social logins. Following this [guide](https://docs.piano.io/oauth-integration/#PKCE) It sends me the login screen and doesn't redirect to give me a code unless someone follows the login flow in the web browser.

The other option I tried was using the `/publisher/login/social/code` endpoint and setting up an authCallback with the app link. Unfortunately this was a dead end because piano overwrites the redirect uri to a piano call back and doesn't send the redirect uri forward.

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this and knows how to make social logins native with piano or can let me know it's not possible so I can go down a different route.